# Перечень — это единое предложение?

Tags: синтаксис

Всегда ли элементы перечня составляют единое предложение с предшествующим текстом?
Или в некоторых случаях возможно рассматривать каждый элемент перечня как особую часть, не образующую с предваряющим текстом целостное предложение?

Comment: Грамматика такими вопросами не занимается. Рассматривайте. Или не рассматривайте. Как вам угодно, это ни на что не влияет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Все-таки перечень - это единое предложение?

Comment: Это вообще не предложение.

Answer (score 2):

Прочитайте статью [11 правил оформления перечня](https://infogra.ru/typography/11-pravil-oformleniya-spiskov-i-perechnej).

Перечень представляет собой законченное высказывание. Однако есть пунктуационные особенности оформления таких высказываний (см.статью).

Рассматривать отдельно какую-то часть перечня вполне можно,  Niemand прав. Если это законченное высказывание, конечно. Будет лучше, если Вы приведёте конкретный пример.

В том, что это обычное предложение, я уже сомневаюсь, хотя начинается высказывание, содержащее перечень, как обычное предложение, а в конце конструкции ставится точка. Очень часто внутри такой конструкции нет отдельных предложений, нет точек, и тогда это очень похоже на предложение.

Но когда внутри конструкции появляются отдельные предложения и точки, сложно отнести её к обычному сложному предложению. Думаю, это что-то вроде сложного синтаксического целого.

В любом случае мой ответ не стоит принимать как верный. Ибо ясности НЕТ.

Comment: Я бы сказал, перечень — это часть предложения (сначала идут предваряющие перечень слова).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, пример из [справочника Лопатина.](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=145) I. Строительные материалы и изделия: 1. Природные каменные. 2. Керамические, получаемые в результате обжига глины. 3. Вяжущие вещества. 4. Искусственные каменные материалы и изделия: 1) силикатный кирпич, 2) асбоцементные и бетонные изделия. 5. Лесные материалы. 6. Металлические материалы. Это единое сложное предложение?

Comment: Лопатин пишет: "Если перечень оформлен как составная часть предваряющего его предложения..." Значит, перечень может быть частью предложения, а может и не быть. Во втором случае, думаю, к такой конструкции понятие "предложение" не применимо.

Comment: Спасибо всем. В следующем неосложненном случае (Вяжущие вещества: 1) известь, 2) цементы, 3) бетоны.) тоже неясно, предложение ли это?

Comment: @М_Г Тоже выскажите, пожалуйста, свое мнение.